# How to check launchOptions in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm pretty stumped here - I'm trying to detect if my app launched from a LocalNotification or not. But all my code is borked.

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    var firstWay = launchOptions.objectForKey(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey)
    var secondWay = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]
    return true
}
```

Both of these fail with the message

```
"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

I am sure I am doing something very basic incorrectly here. Any pointers?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are unwrapping the launchOptions dictionary, which is frequently nil, in your arguments. Trying to unwrap a nil value will lead to a crash so you need to check that it is not nil before using the trailing exclamation point to unwrap it. The correct code is as follows:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    if let options = launchOptions {
       // Do your checking on options here
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 10):

cleanest way:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let notification:UILocalNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {
        //do stuff with notification
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this,

```
let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as! UILocalNotification!
if (notification != nil) {
    // Do your stuff with notification
}
```

Comment: This will crash if notification is nil, even before reaching your test. You shouldn't write things like "as! UILocalNotification!"